# converting iteration into a function

Tags: python, function, iteration

I'm a beginner in Python, and computer languages in general, and I'm totally stumped on how to format this iteration into a function. The iteration takes the sum of someone's birth year, month, and day and adds it together to create a sum of those numbers, and then the second iteration takes the first sum and adds those numbers together to create a final sum. This

I have the users input their birthyear, month, and day (all converted to int) and this is the code for the first sum (Example: A bday of 01/01/1997= 1999):

```
first_sum=b_yr + b_dy + b_mo
```

Then the first iteration takes the sum and adds the numbers together (Example: 1999 = 1+9+9+9 = 28):

```
z = first_sum
zstr1=str(z)
accum1=0
for x in zstr1:
   accum1 += int(x)
(accum1)
```

Then the second iteration takes the first sum and adds those numbers again to create the final sum (Example: 28 = 2+8 = 10):

```
str2=str(accum1)
accum2=0
for cnt2 in str2:
    accum2 += int(cnt2)
```

Comment: Iterations and functions are completely different things. What is it that you want to make into a function and why do you want to do it?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you actually need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the work:

```
def numerology(z):
    zstr1=str(z)
    accum1=0
    for x in zstr1:
        accum1 += int(x)
    str2=str(accum1)
    accum2=0
    for x in str2:
        accum2 += int(x)
    return accum2
```

call to function

```
numerology(first_sum)
```

btw is a strange way of doing it (to me)

edit:
To add to Anonymous's functional way, a recursive one (with list comprehension).

```
def numerology(z):
    zstr1=list(str(z))
    res=sum([int(i) for i in zstr1])
    if res>10:
        res=numerology(res)
    return res
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Could you explain the function creation process? I'm very confused with the whole process.

Comment: Everything except first and last line is your code, so first line define the function (name and z is the argument passed to it), and last line is what (variable) should the function return as value.

Answer (score 2):

You might factor the interesting parts into their own functions.

I'd probably write it like this:

```
def sum_digits(n):
    return sum(map(int, str(n)))

def magic(y, m, d):
    return sum_digits(sum_digits(y + m + d))

print magic(1997, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Good answer. But maybe a little hard for someone who is new to python, and programming in general to understand?

Comment: I like this answer, it is concise and readable. It is also good for new python user to know a little more about python.

Comment: I also think is a good answer but not for beginners, it made me to think in another (recursive way to do it).